# Bitbucket command doesn't work when I want to push project

Tags: git, repository, push, bitbucket

I want to push my project to bit bucket but when I enter "git push ..." I get this lines and no change will be appeared!

```
hesam@hesam-X460-X460DX:~/blog$ git push origin master 
Password for 'https://hesam4g@bitbucket.org':
Counting objects: 106, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (95/95), done.
Writing objects: 100% (106/106), 23.34 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 106 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no change will be appeared"? Are the commits you've pushed not showing up in the web UI or something?

Comment: my commit not showing up in the web and terminal show that message I mentioned!

Comment: Those messages are normal when git does a successful push. If you run `git log origin/master` is your commit there?